# What is the default value of internal [[prototype]] property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop

Every object has a `[[prototype]]` property. By default its an instance of global `Object` constructor.

What confuses me is this code:

```
var obj1 = {};
var obj2 = {};

console.log(obj1.__proto__ == obj2.__proto__); //true
```

Here `[[prototype]]` of both objects reference the same instance of `Object`.

My question is: does JavaScript have a reserved instance of `Object` which is used wherever we haven't specified `[[prototype]]` value?

Comment: both objects "inherit" from the same parent, which happens to be Object. In fact, at the end of all object's prototype chain there is Object.prototype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default its an instance of global Object constructor.

By default, the last object in each prototype chain is `Object.prototype`. It's actually not an instance of `Object`:

```
> Object.prototype instanceof Object
false
```

simply because `Object.prototype` doesn't have a prototype itself.

> does JavaScript have a reserved instance of Object which is used wherever we haven't specified `[[prototype]]` value?

See above.

Comment: Isn't the end of a prototype chain `null`? Reading the [annotated spec](https://es5.github.io/): `starting from any object, recursively accessing the [[Prototype]] internal property must eventually lead to a null value`

Comment: @RGraham: If you want to look at it this way, yes. Changed the wording.

Comment: @FelixKling so we can say default value is `Object.prototype`?

Comment: @FelixKling , I think that depends on object so created. When a function object is created, [[Prototype]] of that function is` Function.prototype`

Comment: @Number945: But `Object.getPrototypeOf(Function.prototype) === Object.prototype`. That's why I said *"... the **last** object in each prototype chain..."*

Answer (score 0):

The prototype of an object in javascript is the prototype property of its constructor.

If you define a new constructor:

```
function MyConstructor() {}
```

All the object instantiated from it has the same prototype, that is the MyConstructor.prototype.

```
var a = new MyConstructor();
var b = new MyConstructor();
console.log(a.__proto__ == b.__proto__); //true
```

In your particular case you are using inline objects {} this objects are created using the default Object() constructor so they share the same prototype for the same rule as above.

Comment: *"The prototype of an object in javascript is its constructor."* Definitely no. `a.__proto__ === MyConstructor` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [answer by Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30806114/2844702) is partially correct.
According to [ECMA 2019](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html) , JS defined many kinds of objects like -

1. [Ordinary Objects](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots)
2. [Function Objects](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects)
3. [Built-in Function objects](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-built-in-function-objects)
4. [Built-in Exotic Object](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-built-in-exotic-object-internal-methods-and-slots)
5. [Proxy Objects](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-proxy-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots)

Based on these object types, `[[Prototype]]` default value is defined.

**Example 1**: For our Ordinary objects like we create `let p1 = new Person();`, we have `Person.protoype` as `[[Prototype]]` value for `p1`. I quote from the [ECMA 2019](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-ordinarycreatefromconstructor) :

> 9.1.13 OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor ( constructor, intrinsicDefaultProto [ , internalSlotsList ] )
>
> The abstract operation OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor creates an
>   ordinary object whose **[[Prototype]] value is retrieved from a
>   constructor's prototype property**, if it exists. Otherwise the
>   intrinsic named by intrinsicDefaultProto is used for [[Prototype]].
>   The optional internalSlotsList is a List of the names of additional
>   internal slots that must be defined as part of the object. If the list
>   is not provided, a new empty List is used. This abstract operation
>   performs the following steps:
>
> 1. Assert: intrinsicDefaultProto is a String value that is this specification's name of an intrinsic object. The corresponding object
>      must be an intrinsic that is intended to be used as the [[Prototype]]
>      value of an object.
> 2. Let proto be ? GetPrototypeFromConstructor(constructor, intrinsicDefaultProto).
> 3. Return ObjectCreate(proto, internalSlotsList).

**Example 2**: Let us take another example of Function Object. We have the following code :

```
var foo = function(){};
function hoo(){};

console.log(foo.__proto__== Function.prototype);//true
console.log(hoo.__proto__== Function.prototype);//true
```

I quote from [ECMA2019](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-functionallocate) again :

> 9.2.3 FunctionAllocate ( functionPrototype, strict, functionKind ) The abstract operation FunctionAllocate requires the three arguments
>   functionPrototype, strict and functionKind. FunctionAllocate performs
>   the following steps:
>
> 1. Assert: Type(functionPrototype) is Object.
> 2. Assert: functionKind is either "normal", "non-constructor", "generator", "async", or "async generator".
> 3. If functionKind is "normal", let needsConstruct be true.
> 4. Else, let needsConstruct be false.
> 5. If functionKind is "non-constructor", set functionKind to "normal".
> 6. Let F be a newly created ECMAScript function object with the internal slots listed in Table 27. All of those internal slots are
>      initialized to undefined.
> 7. Set F's essential internal methods to the default ordinary object definitions specified in 9.1.
> 8. Set F.[[Call]] to the definition specified in 9.2.1.
> 9. If needsConstruct is true, then
>      a. Set F.[[Construct]] to the definition specified in 9.2.2.
>      b. Set F.[[ConstructorKind]] to "base".
> 10. Set F.[[Strict]] to strict.
> 11. Set F.[[FunctionKind]] to functionKind.
> 12. **Set F.[[Prototype]] to functionPrototype.**
> 13. Set F.[[Extensible]] to true.
> 14. Set F.[[Realm]] to the current Realm Record.
> 15. Return F.

This **functionPrototype** is nothing but `Function.prototype`.